# Reduce duplicate VCR.use_cassette scenarios to common subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, vcr

Using VCR in my rspec test and everything is working fine. But I wanna improve the code quality as I have used multiple times same code `VCR.use_cassette` in my test.

Here is the test:-

```
context 'when request authenticated and Params are valid' do
  it 'results should have success' do
    VCR.use_cassette('test_service') do
      post '/rates', headers: auth_headers, params: params
      expect(response.status).to be(200)
    end
  end

  it 'results should have nominal nominal_interest_rate' do
    VCR.use_cassette('test_service') do
      post '/rates', headers: auth_headers, params: params
      expect(response.body).to include('rate')
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body).class).to eq(Hash)
    end
  end

  it 'results should have nominal discount' do
    VCR.use_cassette('test_service') do
      post '/rates', headers: auth_headers, params: params
      expect(response.body).to include('discount')
    end
  end
end
```

As in above code I have used VCR.use_cassette multiple times. I want to make this as a common block and use it multiple time I need. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docs](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/6-0-0/docs/test-frameworks/usage-with-rspec-metadata) you can use "RSpec metadata" and pass the cassette to the example or example group as an argument (`{vcr: 'cassette name'}`) e.g.

"spec/spec_helper.rb"

```
VCR.configure do |c| 
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
end
```

And then

"spec/your_spec.rb"

```
context 'when request authenticated and Params are valid', vcr: 'test_service' do
  before(:each) do 
    post '/rates', headers: auth_headers, params: params
  end
  it 'results should have success' do
    expect(response.status).to be(200)
  end

  it 'results should have nominal nominal_interest_rate' do
    expect(response.body).to include('rate')
    expect(JSON.parse(response.body).class).to eq(Hash)
  end

  it 'results should have nominal discount' do
    expect(response.body).to include('discount')
  end
end
```